# Impossible to dismiss BottomSheetDialogFragment programmatically from AsyncTask after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**I HAVE ALREADY LOOKED FOR ANY POSSIBLE SIMILAR QUESTIONS AND NONE OF THEM ARE RELATED TO THIS ONE AND DON'T PROVIDE A SOLUTION FOR THIS QUESTION.**

I have a basic chat implementation design in which the user opens a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` from the `ChatFragment`.

This `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is responsible for asking the user to confirm he wants to upload the selected file and shows the upload progress after confirmation.

After the upload is completed, the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` dismisses itself automatically.

Everything works perfectly if the user does not rotated the screen when the upload is in progress.

The problem happens when the screen is rotated while the upload is under going.

While it is uploading, the screen is rotated and the upload is completed after that, the `AsyncTask` invokes the Complete listener set by the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

When the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` Complete listener is called, it simply executes the `dismiss()` method, but at this point a NPE is thrown because the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is no longer attached to any activity.

I am looking for a solution that does not involve using `setRetainInstance(true)` (I loose the reference to the `AsyncTask`) nor changing `configChanges` options in the manifest.

So far I've tried as far as going to all the available fragment managers to try and pop the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` from the stack, but since it is no longer attached to the activity all fragment managers are null. I also tried to dismiss it from the `ChatFragment` since it holds a reference to the dialog, but the same problems exist. It feels as if the `AsyncTask` "detached" context is passed down to all the Complete listeners causing all of them to be detached from the activity as well.

Here's the code requested in the comment:

`ChatFragment`

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment { // That's the v4.support fragment

    (...)

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            final FragmentActivity activity;

            if ((activity = getActivity()) != null) {

                final BottomSheet BottomSheet = new BottomSheet();


                final OnFileUploadCompleteListener onFileUploadCompleteListener = new OnFileUploadCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        bottomSheet.dismiss(); // tried just dismiss(); as well, makes no difference if it is dismissed from this class or from the BottomSheet itself
                    }
                };

                bottomSheet
                        .setOnFileUploadCompleteListener(onFileUploadCompleteListener)
                        .show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheet.getClass().toString());

            }

        }

    }

    (...)

}
```

`BottomSheet`

```
public class BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment implements FileUploadTask.OnUploadCompleteListener {

    // the file upload task is initiated when the user confirms the upload

    (...)

    @Override
    public void onUploadComplete(String response) {

        if (onFileUploadCompleteListener != null) {
            onFileUploadCompleteListener.onComplete();
        }

        dismiss();

    }


    public BottomSheet setOnFileUploadCompleteListener(OnFileUploadCompleteListener onFileUploadCompleteListener) {
        this.onFileUploadCompleteListener = onFileUploadCompleteListener;
        return this;
    }


    public interface OnFileUploadCompleteListener {
        void onComplete();
    }

    (...)

}
```

`FileUploadTask`

```
public class FileUploadTask extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, String> {

    private OnUploadCompleteListener onUploadCompleteListener;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(File... fileUploadDataParams) {

        (miscellaneous file upload code)

        return response;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        if (onUploadCompleteListener != null) {
            onUploadCompleteListener.onUploadComplete(response);
        }
    }

    public FileUploadTask setOnUploadCompleteListener(OnUploadCompleteListener listener) {
        onUploadCompleteListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public interface OnUploadCompleteListener {
        void onUploadComplete(String response);
    }

}
```

Comment: would you please add your codes?

Comment: @Mosius Surely, I'll add them right away

Comment: @Mosius The question is now updated with the code snippets

Comment: the best solution to accomplish what you need is using [viewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: A DataBinding model is already being used successfully to resume state after rotation, I don't see how the ViewModel will prevent the detached activity state from occuring since it only stores UI related data.

Comment: You should create the instance of your `asyncTask` in viewModel and notify the fragment to dismiss it self when the`asyncTask`'s job is done

Comment: That brings exactly the same problem, the AsyncTask passes the activity detached state to whichever listener it has set. Adding a ViewModel just adds another step in the listener chain. The ViewModel is not a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174558/discussion-between-mosius-and-shadow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up abstracting the communication layer between the AsyncTask and the class attached to its listeners by moving them to LocalBroadcast receivers. This way the AsyncTask is no longer "leaking" an activity detached state to the listeners.

Moreover, I noticed the upload was one that could be a long running task, for that reason I completely dropped AsyncTask and moved to IntentService.